# How to unbind event handler on bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using bootstrap datepicker, and I added a handler on changeDate event to track any changes to the date in JS. But in some circumstance I need to disable this event temporarily, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [off](http://api.jquery.com/off) for event handler or may use [noop](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noop) function:

```
func = $.noop();
```

Comment: I like the noop function solution, but I'm also curious about the 'off', so JQuery's off also works for datepicker?  Could you please help to explain why it works here?

Answer (score 1):

$('.datepicker').datepicker().off('changeDate', event_handler);